# Failed to decode planned changes for aws_lb_listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I’m trying to create a load balanced EC2 and part of that using `aws_lb_listener`, the plan gets created fine and is something around the lines of:

```
  # aws_lb_listener.app will be created
  + resource "aws_lb_listener" "app" {
      + arn               = (known after apply)
      + id                = (known after apply)
      + load_balancer_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:xxx:xxx:loadbalancer/app/xxx-lb/xxx"
      + port              = 80
      + protocol          = "HTTP"
      + ssl_policy        = (known after apply)

      + default_action {
          + order            = (known after apply)
          + target_group_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:xxx:xxx:targetgroup/tf-xxx-lb/xxx"
          + type             = "forward"
        }
    }
```

But when applying I get the error message:

```
Error: failed to decode planned changes for aws_lb_listener.app: error decoding ‘after’ value: an object with 10 attributes is required (9 given)
```

This is the actual definition of the listener:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "app" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.app.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.blue.arn
  }
}
```

This is the definition of the load balancer:

```
resource "aws_lb" "app" {
 name               = "xxx"
 internal           = false
 load_balancer_type = "application"
 subnets            = module.vpc.public_subnets
 security_groups    = [module.lb_security_group.this_security_group_id]
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you show the actual definition of your `aws_lb_listener`?

Answer (score 0):

Hey discovered the problem, it was an issue of using old terraform (0.14.08) and aws provider versions (~3.0). Updating terraform to (0.14.10) and aws provider (3.36.0) solved the problem....

I think the error message could have been more helpful... :D